# Magento 2: How to get discount price for each cart rule in quote

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules, quote, discount

I need to get all discounted price from each cart rule which is applied on current quote. I am getting applied rule ids from `$quote->getAppliedRuleIds()` and I am getting total discounted amount but I am not sure how can I get discount price of each rule if multiple rules applied to quote.

For example, in quote 3 cart rules applied and each cart rule has different discount(10+20+30) at the code level I am getting total discount amount 60 which is correct but I need (10+20+30) as separate.

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Inject `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` class

```
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $discountAmt = $item->getDiscountAmount(); //$item(get all information)
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, loop through the quote visible items, 
 we will get the discount amount per item-wise.

```
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
$itemDiscountAmount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, try digging in this function

> \Magento\SalesRule\Model\RulesApplier::eventFix

which fires 'salesrule_validator_process' event with discount data for each rule applied.

In your observer, you can put the breakdown in a registry then print them out in a checkout page LayoutProcessor block.

Cheers.